# Example of closed non-exact torsion differential form on variety

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am interested in finding a particular example. I would like to find a variety (analytic or algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$) such that the de Rahm-Sequence is not exact and the variety admits a differential $1$-form $\alpha\neq 0$ such that it is torsion, $d\alpha =0$ and $\alpha \neq df$.

From a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01115106) of H. Reiffen I know that if the polynomial $x^p+y^q +y^{q-1}x$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is irreducible at $0$, then the analytic de Rahm-sequence is not exact ($p\geq 4, q\geq p+1$). However, I have not been able to utilizes this class of examples to produce a closed non-exact torsion $1$-form.

Does someone have an idea of how to approach this or perhaps even an example in mind?

Comment: What you mean by $\alpha$ is torsion?

Comment: @Mohan I mean, that it is a torsion element of the module of differential forms. In terms of germs, I mean it is annihalted by a regular element of the stalk of the structure sheaf.